# React Extended Component Render function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

let say,i have a component, which is in render function of extended component.

as only one render function will call , if i remove the function from "Panel" it will work on "ExtendedComponent", is their any other way. so only by function i can render "SomeComponent" from "ExtendedComponent"

```js
class ExtendedComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this. state = {
            showComponent: false,
        };
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        const {showComponent} = this.state;
        return showComponent ? (
           <SomeComponent content="Message sent" />) : null;
    }

    toggleComponent = () => {
        console.log("came here");
        this.setState(({showComponent}) => ({showComponent: !showComponent}));
    };
}
```

```js
class Panel extends ExtendedComponent {

componentDidMount() {
    this.toggleToast();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hey!!!!!</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use class inheritance. It causes more problems than it solves, is hard to reason about, and the same functionality can be accomplished more easily and cleanly with component composition. https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance What exactly is the behavior you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to have the super component rendering instead of the subcomponent:

- Removing the render method from the subcomponent
- Explicitly returning `super.render();`

The second one is suitable in your case since it would work dynamically.

```js
class Panel extends ExtendedComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { foo: true };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.toggleToast();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.foo) {
      return super.render();
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hey!!!!!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```